# get-ec2instance platform is blank

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-powershell

When i do the following

```
(get-ec2instance -instanceid instance-id | select-object -expandproperty Instances).platform
```

its blank

but in the aws console I do see it in there.

any idea?

Comment: no but it shows the platform for windows OS. just not linux

Comment: Oh! Yes, that property will be populated with `windows`, otherwise it is blank. That matches the documentation.